# Can not use `wrap widget` feature in Android Studio on an OSX

Tags: macos, android-studio

Recently after I upgrade to

```
Android Studio 4.0
Build #AI-193.6911.18.40.6514223, built on May 20, 2020
Runtime version: 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6222593 x86_64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
macOS 10.15.5
GC: ParNew, ConcurrentMarkSweep
Memory: 1237M
Cores: 8
Registry: ide.new.welcome.screen.force=true
Non-Bundled Plugins: Dart, org.jetbrains.kotlin, com.developerphil.adbidea, com.google.services.firebase, io.flutter
```

OSX: 10.15.5 (19F101)

I am unable to use `wrap a ...` feature. Previously I double click or `Option + Enter` I can choose what `wrap with ...` from the popup list like this [article](https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-ide-shortcuts-for-faster-development-2ef45c51085b) says
[image]

I have to open `Flutter Outline` and right click which is clumsy for me.
[image]

**Question:**

How can I enable that feature back?

Answer (score 1):

Go to **Preferences > Editor > Intentions > Dart** and check **Quick assist powered by the Dart Analysis Server.**

Comment: This works fabulously

Comment: It's not working on Android studio macOS!

Answer (score 0):

I think root cause came from upgrading from Android Studio from 3 to 4
Today, I updated `Android SDK` and its plugins. Later it was fixed